# iOS Hybrid App -Appium click() is not working

Tags: appium

I just setup Appium 1.3.6 to test my hybrid cordova iOS app on iPhone Simulator.  Able to find button element and its Text, width,Height.But click() is not working.But I am getting 200 success response for click. Please check the appium logs below.

```
Welcome to Appium v1.3.6 (REV 004f52f249d3513809e7d0734d9205d1fec19f8e)
info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
info: Console LogLevel: debug
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Fly dotREZ.app","platformVersion":"7.0","nativeWebTap":true,"platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iPhone Simulator"}}
info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.6 (java 1.5)
info: [debug] Using local app from desired caps: /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Fly dotREZ.app
info: [debug] Creating new appium session e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879
info: [debug] Removing any remaining instruments sockets
info: [debug] Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock
info: [debug] Setting Xcode folder
info: [debug] Setting Xcode version
info: [debug] Setting iOS SDK Version
info: [debug] Getting sdk version from xcrun with a timeout
info: [debug] iOS SDK Version set to 7.0
info: [debug] Instruments v < 7.1, not checking device string support
info: [debug] Detecting automation tracetemplate
info: [debug] Not auto-detecting udid, running on sim
info: [debug] Parsed app Info.plist (as binary)
info: [debug] Parsed app Localizable.strings
info: [debug] Getting bundle ID from app
info: [debug] Parsed app Info.plist (as binary)
info: [debug] Creating instruments
info: [debug] Preparing uiauto bootstrap
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap dir: /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap
info: [debug] Dynamic env: {"nodePath":"/usr/local/bin/node","commandProxyClientPath":"/Users/rajesh.madaswamy/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js","instrumentsSock":"/tmp/instruments_sock","interKeyDelay":null,"justLoopInfinitely":false,"autoAcceptAlerts":false,"autoDismissAlerts":false,"sendKeyStrategy":"oneByOne"}
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap code: // This file is automatically generated. D...ot manually modify!
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap path: /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-13f238e80ecb92ad.js
info: [debug] Reusing dynamic bootstrap: /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-13f238e80ecb92ad.js
info: [debug] Getting device string from opts: {"forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false,"xcodeVersion":"5.0.2","iOSSDKVersion":"7.0","deviceName":"iPhone Simulator","platformVersion":"7.0"}
info: [debug] fixDevice is on
info: [debug] Final device string is: 'iPhone'
info: [debug] Parsed app Info.plist (as binary)
info: [debug] Wrote new app Info.plist with device type
info: [debug] Checking whether we need to set app preferences
info: [debug] Running ios sim reset flow
info: [debug] Killing the simulator process
info: [debug] Killall iPhoneSimulator
info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons
info: [debug] Cleaning sim data files
info: [debug] Deleting /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Library/TCC
info: [debug] Deleting /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Library/Caches/locationd
info: [debug] Deleting /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Library/BackBoard/applicationState.plist
info: [debug] Deleting /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Media
info: [debug] Deleting /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Library/Keychains
info: [debug] Deleting /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3-64/Library/TCC
info: [debug] Deleting /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3-64/Library/Caches/locationd
info: [debug] Deleting /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3-64/Library/BackBoard/applicationState.plist
info: [debug] Deleting /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3-64/Media
info: [debug] Deleting /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3-64/Library/Keychains
info: [debug] Cleaning sim preferences
info: [debug] Cleaning app data files
info: Couldn't find app directories to delete. Probably it's not installed
info: [debug] Not setting locale
info: [debug] No iOS / app preferences to set
info: [debug] Starting iOS 7.* simulator log capture
info: [debug] Pre-launching simulator
info: [debug] Killing the simulator process
info: [debug] Killall iPhoneSimulator
info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons
info: [debug] Getting device string from opts: {"forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false,"xcodeVersion":"5.0.2","iOSSDKVersion":"7.0","deviceName":"iPhone Simulator","platformVersion":"7.0"}
info: [debug] fixDevice is on
info: [debug] Final device string is: 'iPhone'
info: [debug] Launching device: iPhone
info: [debug] Getting device string from opts: {"forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false,"xcodeVersion":"5.0.2","iOSSDKVersion":"7.0","deviceName":"iPhone Simulator","platformVersion":"7.0"}
info: [debug] fixDevice is on
info: [debug] Final device string is: 'iPhone'
info: [debug] Simulator is now ready.
info: [debug] No device id or app, not installing to real device.
info: [debug] Starting command proxy.
info: [debug] Instruments socket server started at /tmp/instruments_sock
info: [debug] Starting instruments
info: [debug] Instruments is at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments
info: Launching instruments
info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace "/Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Fly dotREZ.app" -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-13f238e80ecb92ad.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {"DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES":"/Users/rajesh.madaswamy/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/thirdparty/iwd5/InstrumentsShim.dylib","LIB_PATH":"/Users/rajesh.madaswamy/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/thirdparty/iwd5"}
info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2015-03-13 17:57:19.701 ScriptAgent[30296:2d07] CLTilesManagerClient: initialize, sSharedTilesManagerClient
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2015-03-13 17:57:19.702 ScriptAgent[30296:2d07] CLTilesManagerClient: init
2015-03-13 17:57:19.703 ScriptAgent[30296:2d07] CLTilesManagerClient: reconnecting, 0x9472910
info: Instruments is ready to receive commands
info: [debug] Instruments launched. Starting poll loop for new commands.
info: [debug] Setting bootstrap config keys/values
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "target = $.target();\nau = $;\n$.isVerbose = true;\n"
info: [debug] Socket data received (2 bytes)
info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: target = $.target();
au = $;
$.isVerbose = true;

info: [debug] Socket data received (27 bytes)
info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":true}
info: [debug] Setting initial orientation to PORTRAIT
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.setScreenOrientation('PORTRAIT')"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.setScreenOrientation('PORTRAIT')
info: [debug] Socket data received (33 bytes)
info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":"PORTRAIT"}
info: [debug] Waiting for app source to contain elements
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.mainApp().getTreeForXML()"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.mainApp().getTreeForXML()
info: [debug] Socket data received (3339 bytes)
info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":{"UIAApplication":{"@":{"name":"Fly dotREZ","label":"Fly dotREZ","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0","x":0,"y":20,"width":320,"height":548},">":[{"UIAWindow":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":tr
info: [debug] Device launched! Ready for commands
info: [debug] Setting command timeout to the default of 60 secs
info: [debug] Appium session started with sessionId e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 303 8761.761 ms - 9 
info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879 {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"webStorageEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"browserName":"iOS","platform":"MAC","javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"networkConnectionEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"app":"/Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Fly dotREZ.app","platformVersion":"7.0","nativeWebTap":true,"platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iPhone Simulator"},"app":"/Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Fly dotREZ.app","platformVersion":"7.0","nativeWebTap":true,"platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iPhone Simulator"},"sessionId":"e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879 200 4.339 ms - 586 {"status":0,"value":{"webStorageEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"browserName":"iOS","platform":"MAC","javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"networkConnectionEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"app":"/Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Fly dotREZ.app","platformVersion":"7.0","nativeWebTap":true,"platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iPhone Simulator"},"app":"/Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Fly dotREZ.app","platformVersion":"7.0","nativeWebTap":true,"platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iPhone Simulator"},"sessionId":"e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879"}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879/contexts {}
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Debugger socket connected to ::1:27753
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending connection key
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending _rpc_reportIdentifier: message to remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__argument":{"WIRConnectionIdentifierKey":"40415480-7ff5-4c0f-a545-741769052f13"},"__selector":"_rpc_reportIdentifier:"}
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__selector":"_rpc_reportSetup:","__argument":{"WIRSimulatorNameKey":"iPhone Simulator","WIRSimulatorProductVersionKey":"7.0.3","WIRSimulatorBuildKey":"11B508"}}
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sim name: iPhone Simulator
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sim build: 11B508
info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__selector":"_rpc_reportConnectedApplicationList:","__argument":{"WIRApplicationDictionaryKey":{"com.accenture.londonVoyage-Extension":{"WIRApplicationIdentifierKey":"com.accenture.londonVoyage-Extension","WIRApplicationNameKey":"Fly dotREZ","WIRIsApplicationProxyKey":false}}}}
info: [debug] Using remote debugger app key: com.accenture.londonVoyage-Extension
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Selecting app com.accenture.londonVoyage-Extension (try #1)
info: [debug] [REMOTE] function () { [native code] }
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending _rpc_forwardGetListing: message to remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__argument":{"WIRConnectionIdentifierKey":"40415480-7ff5-4c0f-a545-741769052f13","WIRApplicationIdentifierKey":"com.accenture.londonVoyage-Extension"},"__selector":"_rpc_forwardGetListing:"}
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__selector":"_rpc_applicationSentListing:","__argument":{"WIRApplicationIdentifierKey":"com.accenture.londonVoyage-Extension","WIRListingKey":{"1":{"WIRPageIdentifierKey":1,"WIRTitleKey":"NavAir","WIRURLKey":"file:///Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/D0CB53D1-EB39-40F2-B8D4-C010C8EE691F/Fly%20dotREZ.app/www/index.html"}}}}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":["NATIVE_APP","WEBVIEW_1"],"sessionId":"e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879/contexts 200 14.960 ms - 98 {"status":0,"value":["NATIVE_APP","WEBVIEW_1"],"sessionId":"e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879"}
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879/context {"name":"WEBVIEW_1"}
info: [debug] Attempting to set context to 'WEBVIEW_1'
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Selecting page 1 and forwarding socket setup
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending _rpc_forwardSocketSetup: message to remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__argument":{"WIRApplicationIdentifierKey":"com.accenture.londonVoyage-Extension","WIRConnectionIdentifierKey":"40415480-7ff5-4c0f-a545-741769052f13","WIRSenderKey":"7f6f5954-242e-42aa-a96b-5686585201f0","WIRPageIdentifierKey":1},"__selector":"_rpc_forwardSocketSetup:"}
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Set sender key
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending _rpc_forwardSocketData: message to remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] got applicationSentData response
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Enabled activity on page
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Checking document readyState
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending javascript command
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending _rpc_forwardSocketData: message to remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] got applicationSentData response
info: [debug] [REMOTE] readyState was complete
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":"","sessionId":"e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879"}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879/context 200 23.866 ms - 74 {"status":0,"value":"","sessionId":"e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879"}
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879/element {"using":"class name","value":"x-button-normal"}
info: [debug] Waiting up to 0ms for condition
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Executing 'find_element' atom in default context
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending javascript command
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending _rpc_forwardSocketData: message to remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] got applicationSentData response
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"5000"},"sessionId":"e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879"}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879/element 200 13.041 ms - 90 {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"5000"},"sessionId":"e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879"}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879/element/5000/displayed {}
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Executing 'is_displayed' atom in default context
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending javascript command
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending _rpc_forwardSocketData: message to remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] got applicationSentData response
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879/element/5000/displayed 200 17.283 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879"}
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__selector":"_rpc_applicationSentListing:","__argument":{"WIRApplicationIdentifierKey":"com.accenture.londonVoyage-Extension","WIRListingKey":{"1":{"WIRConnectionIdentifierKey":"40415480-7ff5-4c0f-a545-741769052f13","WIRURLKey":"file:///Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/D0CB53D1-EB39-40F2-B8D4-C010C8EE691F/Fly%20dotREZ.app/www/index.html","WIRTitleKey":"NavAir","WIRPageIdentifierKey":1}}}}
info: [debug] Remote debugger notified us of a new page listing
info: [debug] New page listing is same as old, doing nothing
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] got applicationSentData response
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Got a blank data response from debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] got applicationSentData response
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Got a blank data response from debugger
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2015-03-13 17:57:25.264 ScriptAgent[30296:2d07] -[ScriptAgent handleAlert:]: script status is 2
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2015-03-13 17:57:25.264 ScriptAgent[30296:2d07] -[ScriptAgent handleAlert:]: Calling onAlert
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2015-03-13 17:57:25.266 ScriptAgent[30296:2d07] -[ScriptAgent handleAlert:]: Call to onAlert returned 'YES'
info: [debug] Emiting alert message...
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879/element {"using":"class name","value":"x-button-normal"}
info: [debug] Waiting up to 0ms for condition
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Executing 'find_element' atom in default context
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending javascript command
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending _rpc_forwardSocketData: message to remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] got applicationSentData response
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"5001"},"sessionId":"e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879"}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879/element 200 8.367 ms - 90 {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"5001"},"sessionId":"e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879"}
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879/element/5001/click {"id":"5001"}
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Executing 'click' atom in default context
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending javascript command
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending _rpc_forwardSocketData: message to remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] got applicationSentData response
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":null,"sessionId":"e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879"}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879/element/5001/click 200 24.389 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":null,"sessionId":"e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879"}
info: --> DELETE /wd/hub/session/e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879 {}
info: Shutting down appium session
info: [debug] Stopping ios
info: [debug] Destroying instruments client socket.
info: [debug] Closing socket server.
info: [debug] Instruments socket server was closed
info: [debug] Sending sigterm to instruments
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__selector":"_rpc_applicationDisconnected:","__argument":{"WIRApplicationIdentifierKey":"com.accenture.londonVoyage-Extension","WIRApplicationNameKey":"Fly dotREZ","WIRIsApplicationProxyKey":false}}
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-13 12:27:20 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
       2015-03-13 12:27:20 +0000 Debug: responding with:
2015-03-13 12:27:20 +0000 Debug: Running system command #1: /usr/local/bin/node /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":true}...
2015-03-13 12:27:20 +0000 Debug: Got new command 1 from instruments: au.setScreenOrientation('PORTRAIT')
2015-03-13 12:27:20 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.setScreenOrientation('PORTRAIT')
2015-03-13 12:27:20 +0000 Debug: target.setDeviceOrientation("1")
2015-03-13 12:27:20 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
2015-03-13 12:27:20 +0000 Debug: responding with:
2015-03-13 12:27:20 +0000 Debug: Running system command #2: /usr/local/bin/node /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":"PORTRAIT"}...
2015-03-13 12:27:20 +0000 Debug: Got new command 2 from instruments: au.mainApp().getTreeForXML()
2015-03-13 12:27:20 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.mainApp().getTreeForXML()
2015-03-13 12:27:20 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
2015-03-13 12:27:20 +0000 Debug: responding with:ue,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0","x":0,"y":0,"width":320,"height":568},">":[{"UIAImage":{"@":{"name":"Default-568h","label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/0","x":0,"y":0,"width":320,"height":568},">":[]}},{"UIAScrollView":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/1","x":0,"y":20,"width":320,"height":548},">":[{"UIAWebView":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/1/0","x":0,"y":20,"width":320,"height":548},">":[]}}]}},{"UIAImage":{"@":{"name":"loading_ani.png","label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/2","x":125.5,"y":249,"width":69,"height":70},">":[]}},{"UIAImage":{"@":{"name":"loading_ani_plane.png","label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,"hint":null,"path":"/0/0/3","x":138.5,"y":275.5,"width":43,"height":17},">":[]}}]}},{"UIAWindow":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1","x":0,"y":0,"width":320,"height":568},">":[{"UIAStatusBar":{"@":{"name":null,"label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":null,"path":"/0/1/0","x":0,"y":0,"width":320,"height":20},">":[{"UIAElement":{"@":{"name":"Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top","label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":"Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top","path":"/0/1/0/0","x":6,"y":0,"width":38,"height":20},">":[]}},{"UIAElement":{"@":{"name":"3 of 3 Wi-Fi bars","label":"3 of 3 Wi-Fi bars","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":"Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top","path":"/0/1/0/1","x":49,"y":0,"width":13,"height":20},">":[]}},{"UIAElement":{"@":{"name":"5:57 PM","label":"5:57 PM","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":"Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top","path":"/0/1/0/2","x":137,"y":0,"width":47,"height":20},">":[]}},{"UIAElement":{"@":{"name":"100% battery power","label":"100% battery power","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":true,"hint":"Swipe down with three fingers to reveal the notification center., Swipe up with three fingers to reveal the control center, Double-tap to scroll to top","path":"/0/1/0/3","x":290,"y":0,"width":25,"height":20},">":[]}}]}}]}}]}}}
2015-03-13 12:27:20 +0000 Debug: Running system command #3: /usr/local/bin/node /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":{"UIAApplication":{"@":{"name":"Fly dotREZ","label":"Fly dotREZ","value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"v...
2015-03-13 12:27:30 +0000 Stopped: Script was stopped by the user
Instruments Trace Complete (Duration : 15.250390s; Output : /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace)
info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 0
info: [debug] Cleaning up after instruments exit
info: [debug] Stopping iOS log capture
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Disconnecting from remote debugger
info: [debug] Running ios sim reset flow
info: [debug] Killing the simulator process
info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Debugger socket disconnected
info: [debug] Cleaning sim data files
info: [debug] Deleting /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Library/TCC
info: [debug] Deleting /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Library/Caches/locationd
info: [debug] Deleting /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Library/BackBoard/applicationState.plist
info: [debug] Deleting /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Media
info: [debug] Deleting /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Library/Keychains
info: [debug] Deleting /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3-64/Library/TCC
info: [debug] Deleting /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3-64/Library/Caches/locationd
info: [debug] Deleting /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3-64/Library/BackBoard/applicationState.plist
info: [debug] Deleting /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3-64/Media
info: [debug] Deleting /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3-64/Library/Keychains
info: [debug] Cleaning sim preferences
info: [debug] Clearing key: SimulateDevice
info: [debug] Writing new preferences plist data
info: [debug] Cleaning app data files
info: [debug] Deleting /Users/rajesh.madaswamy/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/D0CB53D1-EB39-40F2-B8D4-C010C8EE691F
info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":null,"sessionId":"e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879"}
info: <-- DELETE /wd/hub/session/e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879 200 317.723 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":null,"sessionId":"e385db7f-319a-4c0c-888b-1cc14c415879"}
```

Comment: please share your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try next method:
Let `driver` be `Selenium::WebDriver` instance, and `el` your element:

On Ruby:

```
driver.action.move_to(el, 0, 30).click.perform
```

Comment: Is there any reason why click doesn't works? I faced the same issue.